# I want to calculate the difference in hours between two times. What components should i use: DateTimepickers or ComboBoxes

Tags: delphi

```
var
  Hour, Min, Sec, MSec: Word;
begin
  DecodeTime(ComboBox1-ComboBox2, Hour, Min, Sec, MSec);
end;
```

This is the code but it keeps getting errors?

Comment: 1. What do you think should be the difference of two combo boxes??? 2. For date entry DateTimePickers are probably better than combo boxes.

Comment: Life lesson: You will frequently get errors when you decide to just make stuff up. Which part of your training led you to believe that code would do anything meaningful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DecodeTime` expects a `TDateTime` variable. `ComboBox1` and `ComboBox2` are components. Use `TDateTimePicker` and their [DateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.DateTime) properties. (Or possibly the `Time` property if that suits better).

To calculate the hours between both times, use [DateUtils.HoursBetween](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.HoursBetween) instead of `DecodeTime`.

```
hourDiff := HoursBetween(DateTimePicker1.DateTime,DateTimePicker2.DateTime);
```

Comment: You also could use comboboxes, especially when you have a certain limited set of dates which you put in the items list. But you have to acces them by: StrToDatetime(Combobox1.Text) - StrToDatetime(Combobox2.Text)